# How to submit form on file select without page reload?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, form-submit, forms

I'm developing an wireless file transfer app (HTTP Web Server), it contains a website with a form to upload file to the server i.e android app

When I select a file of very less size header generated is as below.

```
            POST /?Upload HTTP/1.1
            Host: 192.168.0.101:4567
            Connection: keep-alive
            Content-Length: 2968
            Pragma: no-cache
            Cache-Control: no-cache
            Origin: http://192.168.0.101:4567
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
            Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryT0t2jgS72DnsVZRX
            Accept: */*
            DNT: 1
            Referer: http://192.168.0.101:4567/
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And when I select a larger file then and error occurs as follow

Console error : (index):637 Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"

Header generated

```
            Provisional headers are shown
            Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0tFAb8kt90pwbuFO
            Origin:http://192.168.0.101:4567
            Referer:http://192.168.0.101:4567/
            User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36

            Provisional headers are shown
            Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0tFAb8kt90pwbuFO
            Origin:http://192.168.0.101:4567
            Referer:http://192.168.0.101:4567/
            User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36

            Provisional headers are shown
            Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0tFAb8kt90pwbuFO
            Origin:http://192.168.0.101:4567
            Referer:http://192.168.0.101:4567/
            User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
```

Code :

```
            <form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input id="uploadPath" type="hidden" name="path">
                <button class="file-upload">
                    <input id="fileUpload" onchange="uploadFile()" type="file" class="file-input">Upload
                </button>
            </form>

            <script>

            function uploadFile() {        
                var form = document.getElementById('uploadForm');
                var path = form.elements.namedItem("path").value
                var file = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0];
                var formData = new FormData(form);

                formData.append('file', file);
                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open("POST", '/?Upload', true);
                http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", file.size);
                http.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
                    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                        alert(http.responseText);
                    }
                }

                http.send(formData);
                form.reset();
                form.elements.namedItem("path").value = path;

            }
            </script>
```

Comment: So, combine the information you got from those posts..?

Comment: can you please help me ? I'm not getting it properly.@Andy

Comment: is "upload" a valid URL with your routing? Also, please post any errors you get in the javascript console or on the actual request itself. "Not working" is not really helpful

Comment: Sorry it upload.php,  but then also it's not working

Comment: (index):628 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined..                here   $("#fileUpload").on("change", function () {
   error

Comment: If you're getting that error, that means you haven't included jQuery in your page. Search for "getting started with jQuery"

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the reference to the jQuery library, and also to place the event handler inside of the document ready function.

Comment: Can you give me the working demo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will listen to the file input, and when the value changes, meaning they have selected a file, it will send an ajax call with your form to the url you specify. This should submit the form without a page reload.

## Updated to include reference to jQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#fileUpload").on("change", function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "upload.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        // success callback
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try looking into AJAX. This will make it possible to update part of your page without a reload, by requesting page fragments from the webserver. The page fragments are then used to update certain elements on your page. See http://www.w3schools.com/ajax for an intro.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out this solution ([jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)). Requires JQuery but is easy to implement.

You could try only using Javascript and AJAX ([Form submission using AJAX, PHP and Javascript](http://www.formget.com/form-submission-using-ajax-php-and-javascript/)), without the need to be dependent on JQuery. This would be a more complex process to build, however it is the best method if you plan on building out more complex form submission features.